# Why does SQLAlchemy rollback on some exceptions but not other?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Why does SQLAlchemy's `session.execute` rollback transactions on some errors -- but not others -- despite having a `try-except` block to catch errors at Python level? I am seeing this issue with queries having *type-conversions*; but it could be happening for others as well.

My expectation is that the *select* query fails, but the *insert* query succeeds. Is there a way to make it work like that for all types of errors?

PS: I am seeing this issue with both `pyodbc` and `mxODBC`.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://SA:P@ssword@localhost:1433/master?driver=MS_ODBC")

connection = engine.connect()
cursor = engine.raw_connection().cursor()

Session = sessionmaker(bind=connection)
session = Session()

create_table = """
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sales;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS product;
CREATE TABLE product(
    idn NUMERIC(9) IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL
);
"""

check_table = """   
SELECT * from product;
"""

delete_table = """
DROP TABLE product;
"""

session.execute(create_table)

session.commit()


def transaction(failing_query): 
    insert_something = """ 
    INSERT INTO product (name) OUTPUT INSERTED.idn VALUES  ('Coke') 
    """ 
    select_latest = """
    SELECT TOP 1 idn FROM product ORDER BY idn DESC
    """

    session.execute(insert_something) 

    try: 
        session.execute(failing_query) 
    except Exception as exception: 
        print(str(exception))

    session.commit()

    print("IDN: ", session.execute(select_latest).fetchall())

    session.execute(delete_table)
    session.commit()


# "SELECT 1 where 1=$a" won't rollback the transaction.
transaction("SELECT CAST('A' AS INT)")
```

Comment: Generally, you would call `session.rollback()` in the exception handler...

Comment: As far as the question as asked is concerned, it probably depends on whether the exception was raised before or after the query made it to the databas. If the exception is from the database, the database itself may mark the transaction as being in an error state and (effectively) roll it back. If the exception happens in Python before the query is dispatched, the `except` will catch it and suppress it so the transaction can still commit.

Comment: @sabik If a `session.rollback` is done, wouldn'y wipe the entire transaction? So, how does one do an **optional** select query within a transaction -- because my use case is something like that?

Comment: If you have to roll back just a single query within a larger transaction, you'd have to use nested transactions; that's certainly possible, but doesn't seem like it should be necessary? How are you getting queries that will actively fail, rather than returning 0 rows?

Comment: Thanks @sabik We have a configuration driven query generator (using templates) that could have issues from time to time. You can answer it as well if possible :-)

Comment: If your query generator from time to time generates invalid queries, that'd be something to fix. It may even be a security issue (potential [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)) if the configuration comes from outside.

Comment: In any case, if the database backend marks the entire transaction as bad on various errors, that's quite reasonable from its own point of view and there's not much you can do about it from Python.